# Facing an issue in PDP page in content in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-view, static-content, pdp

I am getting the below error in console in Magento 2 for js and also due to that my details and review tabs overlap with each other. Can anyone knows how to debug this js.

[image]

Comment: Please click on vm1203:5 and share the error here.

Comment: @Msquare, here is the error from that 
{
    "breadcrumbs": {
        "categoryUrlSuffix": ".html",
        "useCategoryPathInUrl": 0,
        "product": "Attic Tent AT-2  25"x54"x7""
    }
}

Comment: Please check this link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/369972/facing-an-issue-in-pdp-page-in-content-in-magento-2/369973#369973

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Your product name is wrong in your json format. The issue is given below:

```
"Attic Tent AT-2 25"x54"x7""
```

Here you can see double quote is mismatched with your json data that's why it's showing an error. Please update your product name and check it.

Comment: Perfect, in the product name " is written has &quot; , so this causes an issue